# Rotating UI objects in locked position View in Swift iOS 8

Tags: user-interface, swift, rotation, ios8

I have a question. I'm writing an app where in one of its views I want to achieve the next:
the view itself doesnt rotate meaning all the controls etc are pinned to their places BUT the objects (buttons for example) DO rotate on their place place.

The problem is that Autorotate is either rotates everything, including position change of the buttons, or locks everything including keeping button orientation.
From what I understood I can lock the view and do a manual transform every time orientation changes but it seems to me very long and ugly, when Xcode has now all this Autolayout and class sizes etc ...

Is there a more elegant way to do it ?

Comment: Try rotating the layer of the view. And it could solve what you actually want to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate please insane-36?